# Mobile version of meta site?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-norepro

Occasionally I find myself browsing this site from a mobile device, e.g. iOS. On the main GIS.se site things are formatted properly for mobile, but the meta site is not. However, the meta.stackoverflow.com site is, so I think it's just a problem with our site. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: Huh, strange. I tried another SE site as well and it was fine, it's just this one that renders as a full desktop page. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I use Meta GIS SE daily on iOS and have not noticed any problem similar to the symptoms you describe.  However, I do have another problem with SO/SE apps on iOS that I am trying to pursue via [**Meta SO**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214335/have-mobile-sites-for-stack-overflow-exchange-recently-lost-ability-to-store-goo)

Comment: Should work http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/ no issues on a nexus 5.

Comment: Seems fine on my Samsung.

Comment: @Andre yep, added an answer describing how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [clearing the cookies and website data](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1677) from my iOS device's browser (Safari), the mobile meta site now renders properly.